# Compiling Type Script files with dotnet build not working on server

Tags: typescript, compilation, teamcity

We are currently building a new dotnet core application. To be sure that we always deploy the latest *.js files we have decided to ignore the local compiled *.js files with git-ignore.

So these javascript files will not be checked in in our bitbucket repository.

The idea was that when we create a build on our teamcity server the typescript files will be compiled during the build proces to ensure the latest javascript code.

The problem is that the typescript files are not compiling. First I thought it had something to do with TeamCity but that does not seems to be the case. Even with the commandline the typescript files are not compiling. 
When I execute the command on my local machine everything works as expected. But on our build server it does build the project but it does not compile the typescript files.

Has anybody an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kelvin

Answer (score 3):

I think this is related to the question answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48275699/4570... try adding the `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` package and then `dotnet build` should also compile your *.ts files.